# How to override validation error messages for file upload class in CI?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form which has max size limit for attachment when user tries to upload is 10MB ( in my Case). When i try to upload more than that CI redirecting to the form with error message "select a file to upload". But i want error message like this "upload a file which is lesser size than 10MB". How should i over write that error message.

Note: I am using CodeIgniter file upload class entirely..........

Comment: Do `echo ini_get('post_max_size');` and `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');`. Maybe your upload size is limited by php.

Comment: i only limited to 10 MB..........but the error message showing when i tried to upload more than that size is unrelated to context....that error message is "You did not select a file to upload"

Comment: I think if the uploaded file size exceeds that set by php (note: not in codeigniter), the file will be ignored by php. So Codeigniter might be finding no file to upload and throwing the error.

Comment: If you changed the error message, try submitting the form without uploading any file.

Comment: i didn't change error message..............i think it's ignoring file thats y it's giving that error...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `system/language` directory, there is file named `upload_lang.php`. You can modify error messages from there.

Comment: yeah it's correct but the problem is if i try to upload file with more size why it's giving error "You did not select a file to upload"........thats for another error

Comment: its a bad idea to change directly in upload_lang.php as this error message will be shown whenever this condition matches any where in the project in any form.

Comment: If I have more than 1 file upload field in different forms then the above solution will not work.