# Codeigniter File Upload Custom Error Messages

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter's Upload library, but I am familiar with the standard form library. My aim is to instead of use the standard upload library error messages (example: The file you are attempting to upload is larger than the permitted size.) use my own error messages.

In the standard form validation I could use the following code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'The %s is a required field. Please ensure this field contains the relevant data before continuing.');
```

However this method for the Upload Library doesn't seem to be the same as i'm attempting to instead of outputting the standard 'max_size' (upload form config rule) error message i want to use my own that actually includes the max size.

I was unable to find anything on this through Codeigniter's documentation, I will show you the code i am using in both my controller and view incase it is of any help:

controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'New Image', 'trim|callback_valid_upload'); 

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '1';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->upload->initialize($config);

$data['upload_data'] = '';

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
    $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
} else { //else, set the success message
    $this->data['success'] = "Upload success!";

    $this->data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();

}
```

view (to output errors):

```
if (isset($upload_data)) {
  foreach($upload_data as $key => $value) { ?>
    <li><?=$key?>: <?=$value?></li>
  <?php 
  }
}
```

So in short where i have my config items such as `$config['max_size'] = '1';` in my controller i would like to set and error message for it and this doesn't seem to work: `$this->form_validation->set_message('max_size', 'The file you have uploaded exceeds the %s MB file size.');`

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/176029/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172744/how-to-override-validation-error-messages-for-file-upload-class-in-ci

Comment: Is there a way without directly changing the $langs ?

Comment: Define custom error message in the controller or in your own custom error file and append the relevant error as an <li> to an `$error` array.  On the front end do a `foreach` loop an echo each `$error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and example some thing like this for custom error messages.

```
if(file_exists(dirname(FCPATH) . '/install/index.php')) {
  $data['error_install'] = $this->lang->line('error_install');
} else {
  $data['error_install'] = '';
}
```