# Changing custom error message for file upload in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to change the custom error message for file size upload without changing it from the core lang file. I have gone through the below code as the solution to previous asked similar question:

[Codeigniter File Upload Custom Error Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099484/codeigniter-file-upload-custom-error-messages)

But I am not sure as to where to use it. Can anyone guide?

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to use this function in certain function,
you can create your custom validation, since you have can access $_FILES variable, and get the info of the file.

so before you called do_upload()

you have something similar to this :

```
if($_FILES['userfile'] > $somenumber) {
    //error here
} else {
    //ok to upload
    $this->upload->do_upload();
}
```

You can also use form validation custom callback to implement that approach.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods